# How would you make it generic?

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, polymorphism

This following code works properly, but I wanted it to have in generic style.
I tried to write it in a generic way, but I had some problems.
I have a method that is to get some data from two collections from MongoDB.

I use `MongoOperations` from `package org.springframework.data.mongodb.core` to handle MongoDB operations. The method `find` which I am calling, needs parameters: query, and a class of which the Mongo Collection is made of. Classes `EvaluationWork` and `ArchivalWork` implement an interface `WorkContainer`.

What I'd like to do is to make use of that `T` generic parameter, which is upper bounded by `WorkContainer`, by make generic the call of `find` method, instead of `EvaluationWork.class` and `ArchivalWork.class` if possible. And I am also curious whether is possible to have the function `convertToWorkWithId` generic and the possibility to call it in the same way as now, without casting (`.map(w->convertToWorkWithId((T)w))`) ?

```
public abstract class AbstractWorkMongoDao<T extends WorkContainer> {

    protected WorkWithId convertToWorkWithId(WorkContainer evaluationWork) {
        return evaluationWork.getWorkWithId();
    }
    /* there is some code here */
    public List<WorkWithId> getByDate(String institutionId, String startDate, String endDate, boolean repository) {
        Query query = buildSearchQuery(institutionId, startDate, endDate);
        List<WorkWithId> workWithIds = mongoOperations.find(query, EvaluationWork.class)
                .stream()
                .map(this::convertToWorkWithId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(repository){
            workWithIds.addAll(mongoOperations.find(query, ArchivalWork.class)
                .stream()
                .map(this::convertToWorkWithId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
        }
        return workWithIds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with  `convertToWorkWithId(WorkContainer evaluationWork)`?  After all you seem to only use a method provided by `WorkContainer` so what would using generics here change? And are `EvaluationWork` and `ArchivalWork` subclasses of `WorkContainer`? Besides that, why do you want to make it generic if those seem to be the only classes to be applied and `ArchivalWork` only being applied if `repository` is true? Again the question: what advantage do you expect from a generic approach?

Comment: Besides my questions above, one way to simplify it might be to always execute the `EvaluationWork` part and execute the `ArchivalWork` only in case of `repository = true`. You'd probably need to call `addAll()` on the list then. Or, if both extend/implement `WorkContainer` you could just pass the classes you want to use, e.g. `Class<? extends WorkContainer>... containerClasses` and call it like `getByDate( ..., EvaluationWork.class, ArchivalWork.class);`

Comment: Mainly, I am asking for educational purpose, just to know. I expect no special benefits, but I 'm wondering only, about possibilities.

Comment: I will make use of your proposal. Thx.

Comment: Since it's for educational purposes, I'd like to provide one piece of advice from my experience: if you don't _need_ generics for a certain task (i.e. if all that matters is the upper bound like in your case) don't use them. There are several situations where generics can actually cause more problems than they solve, especially when things like reflection (BeanIntrospector etc.) are involved.